# After importing an application from GCM to FCM in the Firebase Console, will Push Notifications continue to work for some time through GCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I have a question about **importing an GCM App to FCM through the Firebase console**.

Can you tell me if **Push Notifications** will continue to work after migrating to the older versions of the App via **GCM**?

In my case it will be a time consuming process, as well as migrating the **GCM** App to **FCM**, I am migrating the app code from an old project made in Phonegap to Cordova, and I need to change the server side to use the new API in Firebase Cloud Messaging, so ensuring that push notifications continue to work through GCM is critical.

Comment: You could test this out. Create a test app with the new FCM implementation and send a push to it with the GCM server side code.

Comment: Thank you @AL. I'm already providing a test App as you suggested. But in parallel, I would like other developers who have already gone through this situation, could leave their contribution with the question, if everything went well for them or had problems.